# Get list of quarter from startDate and enddate

Tags: java, mysql, date

i'm working with Struts2 , JPA  and MySQL in my webApp . In my table i have two column `startDate` and `endDate` and i want to get all quarters between this `startDate` and `endDate` . For example I have two dates below :

```
StartDate  2013-01-23              
EndDate    2015-11-29
```

i want get this list :

```
Jan 2013
Apr 2013
Jul 2013
Oct 2013
Jan 2014
Apr 2014
Jul 2014
......
......
......
Jul 2015
Oct 2015
```

My goal is get all quarters in a select list.

```
Edite 1 :
```

to start i'm working on this query in phpmyadmin :

```
select listt from
(
  SELECT CAST(SELECT `startDate` from tableA AS DATE) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE_ADD(Q,1,DateValue)    FROM    listt  WHERE   DATE_ADD(Q,1,DateValue) < CAST(SELECT `endDate` from       tableA AS DATE)
)

SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH,DateValue))+ ' ' +Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(YYYY,DateValue)) FROM  listt OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

and then put this query in my dao class :

```
public List<Date> listDate() {
        List<Date> pay = null;
        try {
            pay = session.createQuery("My query").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pay;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could show what you have tried already and where that has failed?

Comment: This is easier to do at the application layer.

Comment: @Toby  please see my Edite 1

Comment: @GordonLinoff : can you help me and exlplain how to do it. thank you